# JWindow always on top

Tags: java, swing, always-on-top

I used Java and Swing.

I have two windows `MainWindow` and `PointWindow`.

`MainWindow` is a JFrame window.

`PointWindow` extends `JWindow`.

I want to keep `PointWindow` always on top (never under other windows or components). I set in constructor of `PointWindow` a `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` but problem is when I click to to `MainWindow` (focus), next on different way for example click on my desktop (empty space) and try to drag `PointWindow` then it is under my `MainWindow`.

There is any way to keep the `PointWindow` always on top of all components ?

**EDIT**

In constructor I tried using a `WindowListener` as below

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        toFront();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        toFront();
    }
});
```

... but it do not work, the events are not catched

Comment: setAlwaysOnTop (true);
should do it

Comment: But do not. Problem is showing when I lost focus on `PointWindow`, click on different (not project) place and try to drag.

Comment: you can listen for other events (window state listener) or create a "on top thread" to call .toFront();

Comment: @pzaenger it must be the JWindow

Comment: @JarlikStepsto I try to add in constructor a `WindowListener` with overriten methos as `windowDeactivated` or `windowLostFocus` but it is not catched.

Comment: undecorated JDialog is more confortable than a JWindow,

Comment: Could you post a minimal example? The standard behaviour is that a  `JWindow` with `alwaysOnTop(true)` indeed stays on top of a JFrame. Therefore, I assume something specific to your code changes this behaviour.

Comment: @mKorbel I try to get solution to JWindow, because I set backround and many things that I can not do with JDialog. Try to answer my question.

Comment: JWindow does not receive / process focus events.

Comment: A plain JWindow is not draggable. When you talk about dragging the JWindow, you are invoking custom code which might change the z-order of the components on screen. Could you show the handling of dragging operations?

Comment: @MarkusFischer I add a `MouseAdapter` as `MouseListener` in constructor.

Comment: @Markus Fischer JWindow with parent (JFrame) proceed all events, agree with some problems e.g. JTextComponents arent editable in JWindow without parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I add a `MouseAdapter`as a `MouseListener` to `PointWindow` and when `mousePressed` event is detected then do `toFront()` and work fine but there is one side effect, it means that there is a moment when window is hide and show (very fast).

Answer (score 0):

If both windows belongs to the same application, the

```
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

method should do, what you want.

**If your window have to stay on top, even if your application lost focus**, you have to push it periodically back on top. If another window got the focus, you can not controll that, but you can use a thread to push your window back to top.

In the following example, fr is your window

```
Thread th = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            boolean live = true;
            while(live){
                try{
                    fr.toFront();
                    fr.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                }catch(Exception e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

This code will push your window back to front every 100ms, it should be anough for most applications. This is not the best solution, but it should work

**EDIT:**

**if you just want to the window to be on front of your other window** (event after focus regain), you can add and

a [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) to your JFrame and call toFront on your window, when focusGained(FocusEvent e) event fires.

**Or** you could create the JWindow with the frame as parent:
new JWindow(jframeParent);
this way, your JWindow will recieve all events.

**Or** just using an undecorated JFrame instead of the JWindow

**EDIT2:**

**If you just want the window to be on top, when you click it**, a [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) is the right way to do it.

Comment: Hmm maybe can I detect when my JWindow restore focus and then run the Thread ?

Comment: see the edit. You can detect, when your jframe is gaining focus and push then the window on top of it and set allwaysOnTop again

Comment: FocusListener is do not detect. I found solution as I wrote. Thanks for Your answer :)

Comment: the focus lsitener is only working on the JFrame, not the JWindow. But you can push the window, when your frame get the focus :). Another way would be a undecorated JFrame, which is like a JWindow but focusable. But i added your solution to the answer, so other people have a complete overview :)